# if p implies q then what's the outcome of (p or q) , (p and q)?

Tags: logic

This is actually  a question I had in my course notes if event p implies event q (values of p , q are not given) then what's the outcome of (p and q) , (p or q)

The problem I encountered:

> I was wondering which event i should consider false and which event i
> should consider true , answring this would solve the problem

my attempt:

> if p causes q to happen then outcome of (p and q) should be false as q
> only happens if p happens (they are are dependent events)
>
> and outcome of (p or q) is false (again how can we know if any of them
> happens if they dependent on each other)

I new to logic , sorry if the question is stupid.

thanks in advance

edit :

p:person A goes to some place

q:person B goes to some other place

i had this in the question aswell but it did not add much to it so i did not consider adding it (as the truth values are still not given).

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: my professor's textbook

Comment: Okay; "course notes" might be more appropriate than "textbook", then. I suggest you [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: @Shaun see the edit

Comment: I don't see a change in the use of "textbook".

Comment: @Shaun ah i get you now

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the answer is not a truth table? I think you have the right idea but are slightly confused.

If $P \implies Q$, then $P \land Q$ is $T$ only when $P$ and $Q$ are both $T$.

I will leave the second part for you since this seems to border on a homework problem.

Comment: yeah i made sure it's not a truth table , see the edit it might help.

Comment: hm. Well the truth value of $P \land Q$ and $P \lor Q$ is dependent on the truth value of $P$

Comment: is the question solveable?did i get it right?

Comment: i would like to have some more hints (if possible)

Comment: see the edit at the end of the question please.(it might help)

Comment: I don't see how it's solvable without knowing the truth value of $P$ (unless the answer is a truth table). I have given the truth table for the first part in the above answer, and the truth table for the "or" is as expected. Note that the implication is only F whenever $P$ is F and $Q$ is T

Comment: correct me if i am wrong but if both p and q are true the outcome of (p and q) is true whether p implies q or not , does implication affect the outcome of and/or connectives in any way possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases:

1-

$$\Bigl((P\implies Q )\wedge P\Bigr)\implies $$
$$(P\wedge Q) \wedge (P\vee Q)$$

2-

$$\Bigl((P\implies Q)\wedge \lnot P \Bigr) \implies \lnot(P\wedge Q)$$

We can say nothing about $ P\vee Q$.

Comment: i meant (P∧Q) NOT (P⟹Q)∧P

Comment: @AmirWG I said there are two cases $(p\implies q)and p$ the second is $(p\implies q) and not p$.